# Find mean and mode of a list in column values of pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, mean

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------+
|id  | score                    |review        |
+----+--------------------------+--------------+
|1   |[83.52, 81.79, 84, 75]    |[P,N,P,P]     |
|2   |[86.13, 85.48]            |[N,N,N,P]     |
+----+--------------------------+--------------+
```

The schema of this dataframe is this:

```
root
 |--id: int (nullable = false)
 |--score: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |--review : array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to find the mean of each column value of `score` and mode of each column value of `review` , and create new columns with those. The data-types of these new columns should be float and string respectively. Like this:

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|id  | score                    |review        |scoreMean|reviewMode|
+----+--------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|1   |[83.52, 81.79, 84, 75]    |[P,N,P,P]     |81.08    |P         |
|2   |[86.13, 85.48]            |[N,N,N,P]     |85.81    |N         |
+----+--------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

I have tried it using udf:

```
import statistics
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#define UDFs
def mean_udf(data):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return None
    data_float = [eval(i) for i in data]
    return statistics.mean(data_float)

def mode_udf(data):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return None    
    return statistics.mode(data)

#register the UDFs
mean_func = F.udf(mean_udf)
mode_func = F.udf(mode_udf)

#apply UDFs
df= (df.withColumn("scoreMean", mean_func(F.col("score")))
       .withColumn("reviewMode", mode_func(F.col("review")))
    )
```

But it throws calculation failed error during evaluation (when I do `show` or `collect`).

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a mixture of changing the `mean_score` calculation using and `group by` & `explode` expressions and a custom udf to get the `mode_review` as follows:

```py
# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("score", ArrayType(DoubleType(), True), True),
    StructField("review", ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)
])

# Define the data to be used in the DataFrame
data = [([83.52, 81.79, 84.0, 75.0], ["P", "N", "P", "P"]), ([86.13, 85.48], ["N", "N", "N", "P"])]

# Create a DataFrame with the defined schema and data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Define a function to calculate the mode of a list
def mode_of_list(input_list):
    return max(set(input_list), key=input_list.count)


# Register the function as a UDF (User Defined Function)
modeUDF = udf(mode_of_list, StringType())

# Create a new DataFrame with the following columns: score, review, mean score and mode review
df_result = (df
             .withColumn("score_exploded", explode(col("score")))
             .groupBy("review")
             .agg(avg("score_exploded").alias("mean_score"))
             .withColumn("mode_review", modeUDF(col("review")))
             .join(df.alias("input"), on="review")
             .selectExpr("input.score", "input.review", "mean_score", "mode_review"))

# Display the DataFrame with the mean score and median review
df_result.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this without using any UDF. The method is a bit similar to one of the answers already here. For calculating `mean`, I exoloded the list in every column value and then used `groupBy` and `aggregate` functionalities.

```
# First explode the lists in 'score' column
# This will generate a new column with default name as 'col'
df_score_exploded = (
    df.select(df.id, 
              F.explode(df.score)
             )
)

# Then aggregate on the new exploded column, grouping on the level of original table
df_score_exploded = (
    df_score_exploded 
    .groupby("id")
    .agg(F.avg("col").alias("scoreMean"))
)

# Finally join this new created table with original table
df= (df.join(df_score_exploded,
             df["id"] == df_score_exploded["id"]
            )                                 
            .select(df["id"], df["score"], df["review"], df_score_exploded["scoreMean"])
     )
```

Similarly, for calculating `mode`, I exploded the list in every column value, then used `groupBy` and `aggregate` functionalities to calculate the count of each sentiment in a list and then used `window` functionality to select the sentiment with the maximum count.

```
# First explode the lists in 'sentiment' column
# This will generate a new column with default name as 'col'
df_sentiment_exploded = (
    df.select(df.id, 
              F.explode(df.sentiment)
             )
)

# Then aggregate on the new exploded column, grouping on the level of 'original table + exploded column'
df_sentiment_exploded = (
    df_sentiment_exploded 
    .groupby("id", "col")
    .agg(F.count("*").alias("countSentiment"))
)

# create a window function to sort 'id' wise sentiment in descending order
w = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("countSentiment").desc())

# Select the sentiment with highest count for an 'id'
df_sentiment_exploded = (
    df_sentiment_exploded
    .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w))
    .where(F.col("rn") == 1)
)

# Finally join this new created table with original table
df= (df.join(df_sentiment_exploded,
             df["id"] == df_sentiment_exploded["id"]                                 
            )
            .select(df["id"], df["score"], df["review"], df_sentiment_exploded["col"].alias("modeSentiment")) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.1, you can use Spark built-in functions to compute mean and mode of an array without using windows, `groupBy` and `join`, that may trigger inefficient shuffles

For the mean, you use `aggregate` to compute the sum of elements in an array, then divide it by the size of the array, and finally round the result, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

array_mean = F.round(
    F.aggregate(F.col('score'), F.lit(0.0), lambda acc, c: c.cast('float') + acc) / F.size(F.col('score')),
    2
)
```

Computing mode is more difficult. First, you create a map whose key is the element in the array and value is how often it appears in the array. Then you extract the key with the greatest value, using a combination of `transform` and `array_max` functions:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

array_mode = F.array_max(
    F.transform(
        F.map_entries(
            F.aggregate(
                F.col('review'),
                F.create_map().cast("map<string,int>"),
                lambda acc, c: F.map_concat(
                    F.create_map(c, 1 + F.coalesce(F.element_at(acc, c), F.lit(0))),
                    F.map_filter(acc, lambda k, v: k != c)
                )
            )
        ),
        lambda e: F.struct(e.getField('value'), e.getField('key'))
    )
).getField('key')
```

You can call those expressions using `withColumn` dataframe's method, as follows:

```py
result = df.withColumn('scoreMean', array_mean).withColumn('reviewMode', array_mode)
```

With the input dataframe `df` defined in the question, you get the following result dataframe:

```
+---+--------------------------+------------+---------+----------+
|id |score                     |review      |scoreMean|reviewMode|
+---+--------------------------+------------+---------+----------+
|1  |[83.52, 81.79, 84.0, 75.0]|[P, N, P, P]|81.08    |P         |
|2  |[86.13, 85.48]            |[N, N, N, P]|85.81    |N         |
+---+--------------------------+------------+---------+----------+
```